# Hadoop installation directory

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Which directory is Hadoop installed in Cloudera distribution? Is it in /usr/bin/hadoop?

```
[cloudera@quickstart opt]$ which hadoop
/usr/bin/hadoop
```

I know the software packages are to be installed inside /opt/ directory.

What does Apache recommend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually if you use parcels for Cloudera CDH (which is recommended way to install it) it goes under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH which is in turn symlink to actual CDH parcel. Under this directory you will find structure very similar to what open source Apache Hadoop normally hase under `/`.

More, if you browse under `/` you will find Hadoop normal binaries being symlinks which point to CDH active parcel through alternatives. For example check `/usr/bin/hadoop`.

This installation strategy brings Cloudera with ability to activate new CDH in a second and it looks like normal Apache Hadoop structure. Under `CDH` parcel directory you will find 2-layer binaries structure. For example in contrast to normal Apache Hadoop with entry point `/usr/bin/hadoop` under CDH you will have `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/hadoop` entry point and actual script `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop`.

Libraries are placed in more proprietary manner. All JARS are under `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars` and appropriate JARS in common library directory or product specific ones are just symlinks. For example check `hbase` specific libs: `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/`.